# Getting the longest subpath of a tree-like structure

Tags: java, recursion, depth-first-search

I am writing a function that will help me compute the longest subpath of a tree-like data structure. What I have written so far uses a recursive method to "dig" into each sub-branch - basically a depth-first search. I don't have much control of the `tree` which is just a `Map` where each key is a node and the value for each key is a list of nodes that the key points to.

For example the `tree` map can have:

```
"start" => ["1"]
"1" => ["2"]
"2" => ["3", "4"]
"3" => ["5"]
"4" => ["end"]
"5" => ["end"]
```

I believe the code I have written below solves my problem by populating the `subLengths` list with the lengths of all subpaths in the tree. All I have to do next is reduce `subLengths` to give me the maximum length.

```
private void calculateAllSubPathLengths(String start, Map<String, List<String>> tree, int pathLength, List<Integer> subLengths){
    pathLength++;
    for(String connectedNode: tree.get(start)) {
        if(connectedNode.equals("end")) {
            subLengths.add(pathLength);
            return;
        }

        calculateAllSubPathLengths(connectedNode, tree, pathLength, subLengths);
    }
}
```

I call this function like:

```
int pathLength = 0;
List<Integer> subLengths = new ArrayList<>();
calculateAllSubPathLengths("start", tree, pathLength, subLengths);
// Get max from the subLengths list and move on with the rest of my logic
```

I don't have much control over the data inside of the `tree` map and it does not have any traditional tree like properties like a binary tree has. Nodes in the tree *could* have many branches and it *could* be nested many levels deep. But, this is highly unlikely given my problem domain. However, I would like to make sure that my code could handle more complex trees should those become more likely in the future.

I am posting this question because my gut instinct is that I am not doing this correctly. My questions are:

1. Is there any way to avoid the use of the `subLengths` list?
2. Is there a way to transform this recursive function into an interative one? If not, I will probably add some kind of condition that stops the function once we reach a certain "depth".
3. Are there any other recursion "best-practices" that I am violating?

Comment: This belongs on the code review site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some undefined variables: `links` should be `tree` and `subPathLengths` should be `subLengths`.

Other than these issues, the code appears to work on this case (the longest path is 5), so I'll address your questions and point out a case where your code fails. Throughout, I assume your tree is actually a tree (i.e. acyclic).

1. This appears to be an acceptable method. Your function name is `calculateAllSubPathLengths`, so the list seems appropriate to store all paths. If you want only the longest (which appears to be the case), add a return value for your function and pass the running best as a parameter instead of `subLengths`. You could also pass "by reference" using a single-element `int[] best`, which avoids some comparisons but incurs semantic problems.
2. Sure, you can do this iteratively using an explicit stack which holds the arguments you'd normally pass to the recursive function. Here's one way:

   ```
   class Pair<K, V> {
       K first;
       V second;

       public Pair(K first, V second) {
           this.first = first;
           this.second = second;
       }
   }

   private static int longestPath(HashMap<String, List<String>> tree) {
       Stack<Pair<String, Integer>> stack = new Stack<>();
       stack.push(new Pair<String, Integer>("start", 0));
       int best = 0;

       while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
           Pair<String, Integer> current = stack.pop();

           if (current.first.equals("end")) {
               best = Math.max(current.second, best);
           }
           else {
               for (String child : tree.get(current.first)) {
                   stack.push(
                       new Pair<String, Integer>(child, current.second + 1)
                   );
               }
           }
       }

       return best;
   }
   ```

   [Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/RoughCadetblueKilobyte)
3. Here are a couple "best practices" suggestions for recursive functions:

   - Your implementation forces the caller to be responsible for a number of variables that are essentially local to the recursive function. Write a helper method to encapsulate these variables to offer a clean `calculateAllSubPathLengths(tree);` option to the caller.
   - Incrementing `pathLength` at the top of the function and testing `connectedNode.equals("end")` seems counterintuitive to treating each node or state as a single entity. Your function asks, "is this neighbor of the current node the end?" and "increase the path, then analyze the current node" when it seems more semantic to ask "is this node the end?" and "analyze the current node, then increase the path as we move to a neighbor", respectively. This has logical significance as well; for example, if the start node *is* the end node, your code will fail.

   Putting those items together, here's a possible refactor:

   ```
   private static int longestPath(Map<String, List<String>> tree) {
       return longestPath("start", tree, 0, 0);
   }

   private static int longestPath(
       String current, Map<String, List<String>> tree, 
       int pathLength, int best
   ) {
       if (current.equals("end")) {
           return Math.max(pathLength, best);
       }

       for (String child : tree.get(current)) {
           best = Math.max(
               best, longestPath(child, tree, pathLength + 1, best)
           );
       }

       return best;
   }
   ```

   [Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/RoughCadetblueKilobyte)

   Even here, there are plenty of areas for improvement and generalization. For example, hard-coding `"start"` and `"end"` states undermines reusability.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I will fix the code typos in the original question. I like your first bullet point on question 3 and will definitely move in that direction. 

What is your opinion on using the recursive method vs the non-recursive method that you showed here? The non-recursive method just looks so... ugly and verbose to me.

Comment: You nailed the tradeoff with recursion: you gain readability and elegance in many cases but you sacrifice some speed and the ability to avoid stack overflows. It's up to you which to use when depending on your application. Something like a postorder tree traversal is far more complex to perform iteratively but is only a few LOC recursively. On the other hand, if your tree has a height of a few thousand...

Comment: Also, Java doesn't appear to have a native `Pair` class, so part of the verbosity problem in the iterative version is Java-specific (this would be less ugly in C++ or most any other language, but still more verbose than recursion).

Comment: Yeah the trees in my particular problem will never reach heights in the thousands. I think i'll stay with the recursive approach because it is really elegant!